# Save a file to CSV and get message box for filename

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Im trying to get a VBA Code for this.

I have a .xlsm file in which i want to save one WORKSHEET to a new workbook.

I also want to prevent excel from alerting about the data i will be losing (since im switch from a macro excel to a comma separated value sheet).

**What i do want excel to prompt is a MSGBox requesting the File name for the new document Or save with a specific word and the current month and year *(SAMPLE - MONTH YYYY)***

i want to be able to put something like "TEST" and it gets saved as "text.csv" on the same folder as the running workbook.

The code i have is:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers").Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\NewWorkbook.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Please let me know guys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

    Dim PathCSV As String
    Dim NameCSV As String

    PathCSV = "C:\"
    NameCSV = "SAMPLE - " & Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy") & ".csv"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers").Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:= _
        PathCSV & NameCSV, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Msgbox "CSV file successfully save to " & PathCSV & NameCSV

End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! will this save on the same folder as  wherever the running file is saved?

Comment: No.  But you can change PathCSV = "C:\" to PathCSV = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Comment: Or PathCSV = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

Comment: Im getting an error "Wrong Number of arguments of invalid property assignment. and then highlights "Format"

Comment: What is your Excel version? Where you put this code (module, sheet or wb)?

Comment: I got excel 2013, im putting this on the module worksheet